# File duplicate finder

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-system, hashcode

In an attempt to clean out my picture collection I made a script to find all duplicate files

```
import datetime
import hashlib
import json
import typing
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path


def filesize(path: Path) -> int:
    """returns the filesize"""
    return path.stat().st_size


def hash_first(
    path: Path, hash_function=hashlib.md5, blocksize: int = 65536
) -> str:
    """returns the hash of the first block of the file"""
    with path.open("rb") as afile:
        return hash_function(afile.read(blocksize)).hexdigest()


def hash_all(path: Path, hash_function=hashlib.md5, blocksize=65536) -> str:
    """returns the hash of the whole file"""
    with path.open("rb") as afile:
        hasher = hash_function()
        buf = afile.read(blocksize)
        while buf:
            hasher.update(buf)
            buf = afile.read(blocksize)
    return hasher.hexdigest()


def compare_files(
    comparison: typing.Callable[[Path], typing.Hashable], duplicates: dict
) -> dict:
    """
    Subdivides each group along `comparison`
    discards subgroups with less than 2 items
    """
    results: defaultdict = defaultdict(list)
    for old_hash, files in duplicates.items():
        for file in files:
            results[(*old_hash, comparison(file))].append(file)

    return {
        filehash: files
        for filehash, files in results.items()
        if len(files) > 1
    }


def find_duplicates(
    rootdir: Path,
    comparisons: typing.Iterable[
        typing.Callable[[Path], typing.Hashable]
    ] = (),
):
    """
    Finds duplicate files in `rootdir` and its subdirectories

    Returns a list with subgroups of identical files

    Groups the files along the each of the comparisons in turn.
    Subgroups with less than 2 items are discarded.

    Each of the `comparisons` should be a callable that accepts a
    `pathlib.Path` as only argument, and returns a hashable value

    if `comparisons` is not defined, compares along:
        1. file size
        2. MD5 hash of the first block (65536 bytes)
        3. MD5 hash of the whole file
    """
    if not comparisons:
        comparisons = filesize, hash_first, hash_all

    duplicates = {(): filter(Path.is_file, rootdir.glob("**/*"))}
    for comparison in comparisons:
        duplicates = compare_files(comparison, duplicates)
    return [tuple(map(str, files)) for files in duplicates.values()]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pic_dir = r"./testdata"
    results = find_duplicates(rootdir=Path(pic_dir))

    # print(json.dumps(results, indent=2))

    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    output_file = Path("./output") / f"{timestamp}.json"
    with output_file.open("w") as fh:
        json.dump(results, fh, indent=2)
```

Any remarks on this code?

The code is formatted with `black` (linelength 79), with `mypy` `pylint` and `pylama` as linters.

If I try to specify the `dict` as argument and return value to `compare_files` to `typing.Dict[typing.Tuple[typing.Hashable, ...], typing.Iterable[Path]]`, `mypy` complains: `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dict[Tuple[Hashable, ...], Iterable[Path]]", variable has type "Dict[Tuple[], Iterator[Path]]")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Instead of `rootdir.glob("**/*")` you can write `rootdir.rglob("*")`. [`rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) adds "`**/`" automatically before the given pattern.
2. You specify the return type of the `comparison` functions as `Hashable`. I'm not really sure why. Are you thinking that you will have more `comparison` functions in the future that would return something other than `int` or `str`? I think you could limit it to `FileHash = Union[int, str]` for now. I doubt that you will have functions that would return such hashable objects as, for example,  `namedtuple`s or `frozenset`s.
3. Maybe I don't understand something, but I don't really see the point why `compare_files` function exists. I would expect it to take as an argument an iterable of paths to the files, but instead, it takes them packed in a dictionary which doesn't make much sense to me. By taking the logic out of it to the outer `find_duplicates` function you will also avoid the problem with mypy complaining about incompatible types. It could look, for example, like this

   ```
   FileHash = Union[int, str]
   Hashes = Tuple[FileHash, ...]


   def find_duplicates(rootdir: Path,
                       comparisons: Iterable[Callable[[Path], FileHash]] = ()
                       ) -> List[Tuple[str, ...]]:
       if not comparisons:
           comparisons = filesize, hash_first, hash_all

       files = filter(Path.is_file, rootdir.rglob("*"))

       files_per_hashes: Dict[Hashes, List[Path]] = defaultdict(list)
       for file in files:
           key = tuple(hasher(file) for hasher in comparisons)
           files_per_hashes[key].append(file)
       duplicates = (files for files in files_per_hashes.values() 
                     if len(files) > 1)
       return [tuple(map(str, files)) for files in duplicates]
   ```
4. You are missing type hints for `hash_function`s. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to solve the problem with their return types. If you are on Python 3.7, you could try something like this (idea taken from https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/2928):

   ```
   from __future__ import annotations

   Hasher = Union[Callable[[ByteString], hashlib._hashlib.HASH],
                  Callable[[], hashlib._hashlib.HASH]]
   ...
   def hash_first(path: Path,
                  hash_function: Hasher = hashlib.md5,
                  blocksize: int = 65536) -> str:
   ...
   ```

   but mypy doesn't like it. It says:

   ```
   error: Name 'hashlib._hashlib.HASH' is not defined
   ```

   Maybe you could dig a bit more in this direction.
5. I also think that it would be better to make the `comparisons` as an `Optional` argument in the `find_duplicates` function with default value set to `None` because right now you use tuple as an immutable version of list (the data you keep in that tuple is homogeneous but tuples are meant to keep heterogenous data, and the number of elements in the tuples is usually fixed). As Guido van Rossum said: ["*Tuples are *not* read-only lists.*"](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-dev/%3C200303120211.h2C2BCH28989@pcp02138704pcs.reston01.va.comcast.net%3E/)

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- I would usually inline single line functions unless what they do is hard to understand from just reading the command. `filesize` might be one such candidate.
- I believe that not specifying the block size can be faster, by allowing Python to use whatever block size it thinks is appropriate. This would need some actual testing though.
- Your function arguments are only partially typed. You might want to use a stricter `mypy` configuration, such as the following, in your setup.cfg:

  ```
  [mypy]
  check_untyped_defs = true
  disallow_untyped_defs = true
  ignore_missing_imports = true
  no_implicit_optional = true
  warn_redundant_casts = true
  warn_return_any = true
  warn_unused_ignores = true
  ```
- MD5 was optimized for cryptographic use, not for speed. [Another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5400275/96588) explores options for fast non-cryptographic hashing.
- I would avoid converting digests to strings - it might be slightly easier for debugging purposes, but data type conversions are in general very costly.
- Optional parameters mean you have to test at least *two* things rather than one. Your code only ever calls the `hash_*` functions without optional parameters, so you might as well either inline them.
- On a related note, static values which are used in multiple places are perfect for pulling out as constants. The hashing function and block size would be obvious candidates for this.
- [Mutable default parameter values](https://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) are an accident waiting to happen. The default pattern for this is to use a default of `None` and to assign a default `if foo is None`.
- r-strings like `r"./testdata"` are meant for regular expressions. Since `pic_dir` is not used as such it should probably be a regular string.
- `duplicates` is at first a list of *potential* duplicates and later is trimmed in stages. This makes the code hard to follow.
- Things like the directory/directories to include should be arguments. [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) can deal with this easily.
- To make this more scriptable I would print the result on standard output. It's trivial to then redirect it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing my own answer here because I incorporated some of the remarks of both other answers, 
and ignored other ones. In this answer I explain why I took certain design choices.

## @[Georgy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/223202/123200):

1. good tip
2. I don't expect much other than `str` and `int`, but `bytes` is a possibility too (`hash.digest`)
3. The use of `compare_files` is to also whittle the subgroups down (if len(files) > 1). 
   I stagger the comparisons from fast to more expensive.
   There might be a lot of files with the same size, but if they don't have the same checksum in their first few bytes, 
   there is no use in comparing the complete file. When done with an step in between logging how much files got compared at each stage,
   I saw the numbers dwindling step per step.
4. the typeshed has a class signature for "hashlib._Hash", so I adapted this to a `typing.Protocol`

## @[l0b0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/223171/123200)

1. I didn't inline them because I want to refer to them as named functions. I could make lambda's out of them, but that signifies the intent less than a named function `filesize`
2. I suggest a blocksize here to prevent python from reading in complete 8GB files into memory to take a digest`
3. nice tip on the stricter mypy. It's tedious to do this for an existing code base, but it has showed me some bugs I wouldn't have otherwise spotted otherwise, so I'm gradually introducing this elsewhere as well.
4. I used md5 because I could easily verify the md5hash against an external tool to test my implementation. Later I moved to CRC32.
5. In my first versions I exported the `duplicates` in between iterations, and then a string representation was handy, and to compare it to the output of external tools to compute the hash
6. True
7. good tip
8. Where did I use a mutable default parameter?
9. I use r-strings for Windows paths as well. Then I don't have to escape all the `\`. Recently I found out VS Code makes a distinction in how it represents `r` and `R` strings, so I switched to `R` (Apparently `black` doesn't like them, and changes them to `r""`)
10. That is the tricky part I have not been able to convey cleanly, but this is to dwindle down the more expensive operations. I renamed it to `potential_duplicates`
11. and 12. Correct, and this might be a good opportunity for a next version.

## Other things

- I include `pydocstyle` in my routing, so the docstring requirements have become a bit more strict. I haven't found the patience to annotate every parameter. I hope the variable names are clear enough
- I included a `min_filesize` argument to `find_duplicates` to be able to focus on the larger duplicates when trying to reduce disk usage

---

crc32.hash.py

```
"""CRC32 adapted to the `hashlib._Hash` protocol."""
from __future__ import annotations

import typing
import zlib


class Hash(typing.Protocol):
    """Protocol for a hash algorithm."""

    digest_size: int
    block_size: int

    name: str

    def __init__(
        self, data: typing.Union[bytes, bytearray, memoryview] = ...
    ) -> None:
        """Protocol for a hash algorithm."""
        ...

    def copy(self) -> Hash:
        """Return a copy of the hash object."""
        ...

    def digest(self) -> bytes:
        """Return the digest of the data passed to the update() method."""
        ...

    def hexdigest(self) -> str:
        """Like digest() except the digest is returned as a string object.

        Like digest() except the digest is returned as a string object
        of double length, containing only hexadecimal digits.
        """
        ...

    def update(self, arg: typing.Union[bytes, bytearray, memoryview]) -> None:
        """Update the hash object with the bytes-like object."""
        ...


class CRC32(Hash):
    """Adapts zlib.crc32" for the hashlib protocol."""

    # docstring borrowed from https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html
    digest_size = -1
    block_size = -1

    name = "crc32"

    def __init__(self, data: typing.Union[bytes, bytearray, memoryview] = b""):
        """Adapts zlib.crc32" for the hashlib protocol."""
        self._checksum = zlib.crc32(bytes(data))

    def copy(self) -> CRC32:
        """Return a copy of the hash object."""
        duplicate = CRC32()
        duplicate._checksum = self._checksum
        return duplicate

    def digest(self) -> bytes:
        """Return the digest of the data passed to the update() method."""
        return self._checksum.to_bytes(2, byteorder="big")

    def hexdigest(self) -> str:
        """Like digest() except the digest is returned as a string object.

        Like digest() except the digest is returned as a string object
        of double length, containing only hexadecimal digits.
        """
        return f"{self._checksum:X}"

    def update(self, arg: typing.Union[bytes, bytearray, memoryview]) -> None:
        """Update the hash object with the bytes-like object."""
        self._checksum = zlib.crc32(arg, self._checksum)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_files = {"CHANGELOG.rst": "C171C371"}
    for filename, expected in test_files.items():
        with open(filename, "rb") as f:
            checksum = CRC32(f.read()).hexdigest()

        print(f"{filename}: expected: {expected}; calculated: {checksum}")
```

find_duplicates.py

```
"""Code to find duplicate files."""
from __future__ import annotations

import datetime
import hashlib
import json
import typing
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path

from crc32hash import CRC32, Hash

_Duplicates = typing.Mapping[
    typing.Tuple[typing.Hashable, ...], typing.Iterable[Path]
]
DEFAULT_BLOCKSIZE = 65536


def filesize(path: Path) -> int:
    """Return the filesize."""
    return path.stat().st_size


def hash_first(
    path: Path,
    hash_function: typing.Callable[[bytes], Hash] = hashlib.sha256,
    blocksize: int = DEFAULT_BLOCKSIZE,
) -> str:
    """Return the hash of the first block of the file."""
    with path.open("rb") as afile:
        return hash_function(afile.read(blocksize)).hexdigest()


def hash_all(
    path: Path, hash_function: typing.Callable[[bytes], Hash] = hashlib.sha256,
) -> str:
    """Return the hash of the whole file."""
    with path.open("rb") as afile:
        hasher = hash_function(b"")
        buf = afile.read(DEFAULT_BLOCKSIZE)
        while buf:
            hasher.update(buf)
            buf = afile.read(DEFAULT_BLOCKSIZE)
    return hasher.hexdigest()


def crc_first(path: Path, blocksize: int = DEFAULT_BLOCKSIZE,) -> str:
    """Return the crc32 hash of the first block of the file."""
    return hash_first(path=path, hash_function=CRC32, blocksize=blocksize)


def crc32_all(path: Path) -> str:
    """Return the crc32 hash of the whole file."""
    return hash_all(path=path, hash_function=CRC32)


def compare_files(
    comparison: typing.Callable[[Path], typing.Hashable],
    potential_duplicates: _Duplicates,
) -> _Duplicates:
    """Subdivide each group along `comparison`.

    Discards subgroups with less than 2 items
    """
    results: typing.DefaultDict[
        typing.Tuple[typing.Hashable, ...], typing.List[Path]
    ] = defaultdict(list)
    for old_hash, files in potential_duplicates.items():
        for file in files:
            results[(*old_hash, comparison(file))].append(file)

    return {
        filehash: files
        for filehash, files in results.items()
        if len(files) > 1
    }


def find_duplicates(
    rootdir: Path,
    comparisons: typing.Optional[
        typing.Iterable[typing.Callable[[Path], typing.Hashable]]
    ] = None,
    min_filesize: typing.Optional[int] = None,
) -> typing.List[typing.Tuple[str, ...]]:
    """Find duplicate files in `rootdir` and its subdirectories.

    Returns a list with subgroups of identical files

    Groups the files along the each of the comparisons in turn.
    Subgroups with less than 2 items are discarded.

    Each of the `comparisons` should be a callable that accepts a
    `pathlib.Path` as only argument, and returns a hashable value

    if `comparisons` is not defined, compares along:
        1. file size
        2. CRC32 hash of the first block (65536 bytes)
        3. CRC32 hash of the whole file
    """
    if comparisons is None:
        comparisons = [filesize, crc_first, crc32_all]

    potential_duplicates: _Duplicates = {
        (): (file for file in rootdir.rglob("*") if file.is_file())
    }
    if min_filesize is not None:
        potential_duplicates = {
            key: (file for file in files if filesize(file) > min_filesize)
            for key, files in potential_duplicates.items()
        }

    for comparison in comparisons:
        potential_duplicates = compare_files(comparison, potential_duplicates)
    return [tuple(map(str, files)) for files in potential_duplicates.values()]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    duplicate_dir = Path(r".")
    results = find_duplicates(rootdir=duplicate_dir, min_filesize=int(1e8))

    # print(json.dumps(results, indent=2))

    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    output_file = Path("./output") / f"{timestamp}.json"
    with output_file.open("w") as fh:
        json.dump(results, fh, indent=2)
```